# Добавить ссылку

Tags: asp.net

Начинаю осваивать ASP.NET Уже два дня мучаюсь никак немогу сделать директиву SportsStore.Domain видимой в SportsStore.WebUI.
Cледовал всем найденым рекомендациям типа: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344295/im-getting-the-missing-a-using-directive-or-assembly-reference-and-no-clue-wh

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто столкнулся?

Comment: Всегда добавляйте метку используемого языка (C#, VB.NET, etc) - это привлечёт к вопросу больше внимания. Вместо скриншота выкладывайте код текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто не объявил класс публичнымю
class xxx{} a надо было public class xxx{}